# Displaying Precipitation Lines in R?

Tags: r, isohyetal

I am working on a map to overlay precipitation lines onto Africa, the end goal being to interpret plant growth in different regions. I got a map up, and most of the precipitation lines look fine, but in some cases there are straight lines cutting through portions of the map that probably should not be there.

I am more or less new at this stuff.

Here's the map output:

[image: AficaPrecipMap]

And here is the code that got me there:

```
precip <- readOGR(dsn="PrecipSHP", layer = "precip_contours", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
precip_f <- fortify(precip)

africa_countries <- readOGR(dsn="Africa", layer= "AfricanCountries", 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
africa_main <- subset(africa_countries, Land_Type == "Primary land")
country_names <- africa_main@data$COUNTRY
center_pts <- gCentroid(africa_main, byid=TRUE)
labels <- cbind.data.frame(country_names, center_pts@coords[,1], 
center_pts@coords[,2]) 
names(labels) <- c("country","x","y")

africa_f <- fortify(africa_main, region = "COUNTRY")

africa <- get_map(location = c(-19,-36,52,38), zoom = 4, maptype = 
"watercolor")
africa <- ggmap(africa)
africa <- africa + 
  geom_map(data=africa_f, map=africa_f, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id), color 
="white", fill ="orangered4", alpha = .4, size = .2)
africa <- africa + annotate("text", x = labels$x, y = labels$y, label = 
labels$country, size = 2) +
  geom_path(data = precip, aes(x = long, y = lat))
```

This comes out of a larger program, but I tested the code above alone and it worked to produce the map above. You can see that some of the lines, especially in the south, look a bit odd.

Why is that?

Comment: Try plotting your contours using plot(precip) to see if the artifacts are really there (I imagine that they are). If so, this has nothing to do with R but rather in how the imported "precip_contours" shapefile was created. In this case you need to backtrack your data workflow or data sources.